# wrong section TAG value

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, sectionedrecyclerviewadapter

I'm try to remove some rows from section one and some from section two, but

```
sectionAdapter.notifyItemRemovedFromSection(TAG, key);
```

TAG always return the 2st section list string TAG, but I was selected row in first list

here is full class code:

```
class ContactsSection extends StatelessSection {

    final String TAG;
    String title;
    List<Item> list;
    ItemViewHolder row;
    HeaderViewHolder MainRow;

    ContactsSection(String title, ArrayList<Item> list) {
        super(R.layout.shopping_row_item_header, R.layout.shopping_row_item);
        this.title = title;
        this.list = list;
        this.TAG = title;
    }

    @Override
    public int getContentItemsTotal() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder getItemViewHolder(View view) {
        return new ItemViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindItemViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        final ItemViewHolder itemHolder = (ItemViewHolder) holder;
        final Item name = list.get(position);
        itemHolder.tvItem.setText(name.name);
        ((ItemViewHolder) holder).IntegBOX.setChecked(name.checked);
        ((ItemViewHolder) holder).IntegBOX.setTag(position);


        deleteAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Iterator it = selectedCheckBox.entrySet().iterator();
                if (!it.hasNext()) {

                    new makeDialog().makeDialog(mActivity, mActivity.getResources().getString(R.string.share_no_data));

                } else {


                    while (it.hasNext()) {
                        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
                        int key = (Integer) pair.getKey();
                        if ((Boolean) pair.getValue()) {
                            list.remove(key);

     // problem Here 
                            sectionAdapter.notifyItemRemovedFromSection(TAG, key);               

 }


                    }

                    chooseAllradioButton.setSelected(false);
                }
            }
        });


        itemHolder.IntegBOX.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //Set the button's appearance
                ((CheckBox) v).setChecked(!((CheckBox) v).isChecked());

                // if button Already in checked statue
                if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {

                    Iterator it = selectedCheckBox.entrySet().iterator();
                    while (it.hasNext()) {
                        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
                        int key = (Integer) pair.getKey();
                        if (key == (Integer) v.getTag()) {
                            it.remove();
                        }
                        // set it as false
                        ((CheckBox) v).setChecked(false);
                    }
                } else {
                    // Otherwise set it to true and add it to hashMap
                    ((CheckBox) v).setChecked(true);
                    selectedCheckBox.put((Integer) v.getTag(), true);
                }


                Toast.makeText(mActivity, String.format("Clicked on position #%s of Section %s", sectionAdapter.getPositionInSection(itemHolder.getAdapterPosition()), title), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder getHeaderViewHolder(View view) {
        return new HeaderViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindHeaderViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
        HeaderViewHolder headerHolder = (HeaderViewHolder) holder;
        headerHolder.tvTitle.setText(title);
    }

    // Remove All Btn Fuc





    class HeaderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private final TextView tvTitle;

        HeaderViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.DishName);
        }
    }

    class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

        private final View rootView;
        private final TextView tvItem;
        private final CheckBox IntegBOX;

        ItemViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            rootView = view;
            tvItem = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.DishName);
            IntegBOX = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.chooseDish);
            IntegBOX.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            //   int position = getAdapterPosition();
            //   list.get(position).checked = isChecked;
        }
    }


}


private class Item {
    String name;
    boolean checked;

    Item(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        checked = false;
    }
}
```

add sections code :

```
     for (int d = 0; d < DishesIngredientsShoppingList.size(); d++) {
        contacts = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < DishesIngredientsShoppingList.get(d).getGroups().length; i++) {
            for (int g = 0; g < DishesIngredientsShoppingList.get(d).getGroups()[i].getIngredients().length; g++) {
                if (Language)
                    contacts.add(new Item(DishesIngredientsShoppingList.get(d).getGroups()[i].getIngredients()[g].getName()));
                else
                    contacts.add(new Item(DishesIngredientsShoppingList.get(d).getGroups()[i].getIngredients()[g].getNameEnglish()));


            }
        }

     sectionAdapter = new SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter();
    ArrayList<Item> contacts = new ArrayList<>();
    // ArrayList<String> dishNames = new ArrayList<>();
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mActivity));
             if (Language)
            sectionAdapter.addSection(DishesIngredientsShoppingList.get(d).getName(), new ContactsSection(DishesIngredientsShoppingList.get(d).getName(),contacts));
        else
            sectionAdapter.addSection(DishesIngredientsShoppingList.get(d).getEnglishName(), new ContactsSection(DishesIngredientsShoppingList.get(d).getEnglishName(),contacts));


    }
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(sectionAdapter);
```

note : i have delete button is setup at action bar not in every row 
so when the code runs the code can not detect current row section tag

Comment: you said you have the delete button in the action bar, so why is its click event set inside the Section.onBindItemViewHolder and not in the activity?

Comment: check this screen shot from my app that i working on please http://prntscr.com/f3p3yl you will see there is only one delete button , and two or more sections and every row has select button , and there is choose all radio button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are storing all the selected checkboxes from all sections in this `selectedCheckBox` map, but when the `deleteAll` button is tapped you call `notifyItemRemovedFromSection` from the section where it is in.

You will have to change your `selectedCheckBox` map to also store which section 'tag' that checkbox belongs to, then when you call `notifyItemRemovedFromSection` you can pass the correct 'tag'.

Comment: very nice thank you , but now , when dealing with list.remove(position) it returns the last section , so how to delete item from section one then move to section two then return to section one .. so on , because delete all button has loop over selectedCheckBox  as you said

Comment: well that's not how Stack Overflow works, did my answer solved the initial problem you asked? if yes, mark my answer as correct. If you now have a new/different issue please open another question and explain it properly

Comment: otherwise it will be like in your previous [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459126/can-not-handle-delete-multiple-selection-in-sectioned-recyclerview/43502884?noredirect=1#comment74497454_43502884) that never ended because you always have a new issue

Comment: here is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43766211/can-not-get-current-list-valeus